# How to unblock requests from my server?

Tags: .htaccess

I have this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^-?$
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

How to change it so it will not accept request without user agent except for those requests that are from IP 292.192.192.212 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use another `RewriteCond` with  `%{REMOTE_ADDR}` variable that represents remote IP address of the client:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^292\.192\.192\.212$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^-?$
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```